# laravel вывод товаров

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ооп, mvc

Нужно вывести на страницу, записи из бд, а именно боковое меню и список товаров. Меню выводится, а список товаров нет. Если убрать меню то список товаров выводится. Вообщем вместе не выводятся данные из бд. Возможно я не так понял как взаимодействуют между собой контроллеры и роуты. Очень буду благодарен за хороший ответ. Код ниже:

```
          //Роуты//
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@tovar');
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@menu');
    Route::get('/contacts', 'SiteController@contacts');
    Route::get('/category/{id}', 'SiteController@category');


    //контроллеры//

   <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Menu;
    use App\Tovar;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class SiteController extends Controller
    {
     public function index()
    {
     return view('index');
    }

     public function category()
   {
      return view('category');
    }

     public function contacts()
    {
     return view('contacts');
    }
     public function menu()
    {
     $menus = Menu::all();
     return view('index', compact('menus'));
    }
     public function tovar()
    {
     $tovars = Tovar::all();
     return view('index', compact('tovars'));
    }
   }

 // боковое меню
 <div class="content__left">
    <a href="" class="content__left-title">Каталог товаров</a>
    @foreach ($menus as $menu)
    <ul class="left__menu">
        <li class="left__menu-item"><a href="{{url("public/$menu->url")}}">{{ $menu->title }}</a></li>
    </ul>@endforeach
</div>

  // файл index.blade.php  -  вывод товаров 

                 <div class="content__right-hit">
            <h3 class="content__right-title">Хиты перодаж</h3>
            @foreach ($tovars as $tovar)
            <div class="products">
                <div class="products__item">
                    <img src="images/westa.jpeg" class="products__item-img">
                    <h3 class="products__item-title">Аккумулятор Westa 60</h3>
                    <div class="products__item-price">
                        <span class="price">4999 Р</span>
                        <a class="addCart">В корзину</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hr">
                        <a class="addCompare">Сравнить</a>
                        <span class="">В наличии</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item">
                    <img src="images/westa.jpeg" class="products__item-img">
                    <h3 class="products__item-title">Аккумулятор Westa 60</h3>
                    <div class="products__item-price">
                        <span class="price">4999 Р</span>
                        <a class="addCart">В корзину</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hr">
                        <a class="addCompare">Сравнить</a>
                        <span class="">В наличии</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item">
                    <img src="images/westa.jpeg" class="products__item-img">
                    <h3 class="products__item-title">Аккумулятор Westa 60</h3>
                    <div class="products__item-price">
                        <span class="price">4999 Р</span>
                        <a class="addCart">В корзину</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hr">
                        <a class="addCompare">Сравнить</a>
                        <span class="">В наличии</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item">
                    <img src="images/westa.jpeg" class="products__item-img">
                    <h3 class="products__item-title">Аккумулятор Westa 60</h3>
                    <div class="products__item-price">
                        <span class="price">4999 Р</span>
                        <a class="addCart">В корзину</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hr">
                        <a class="addCompare">Сравнить</a>
                        <span class="">В наличии</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="products__item">
                    <img src="images/westa.jpeg" class="products__item-img">
                    <h3 class="products__item-title">Аккумулятор Westa 60</h3>
                    <div class="products__item-price">
                        <span class="price">4999 Р</span>
                        <a class="addCart">В корзину</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hr">
                        <a class="addCompare">Сравнить</a>
                        <span class="">В наличии</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>@endforeach
        </div>
```

Comment: А где товары в представлении?

Comment: Добавил вывод товаров.

Comment: И почему у вас на один роут сразу три экшена?

Comment: А можно не умничать и показать где ошибка и как надо???

Comment: Вы месяц назад задавали тот же вопрос, но видимо так и не поняли что для роута должен существовать __только один__ экшен.

Comment: В тот раз так и не нашел правильное решение, поэтому и оставил так, как сделать по другому тогда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запомните **раз и навсегда** - для роута существует только один экшен:

```
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
```

В экшене `index` собираете все нужные для страницы данные и отдаете в шаблон:

```
public function index()
{
    return view(
         'index',
         [
             'menus' => Menu::all(),
             'tovars' => Tovar::all(),
         ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, просто не хватает знаний, можете посоветовать какую нибудь литературу, кроме документации?

Comment: вот курсы хорошие - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7FQEutaCiQ&index=1&list=PLl_kpL5cwH6LLuvd_xXOplXejM7shFhme